# Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to observe a list of all of the exercise names from my ROOM database inside my `AlertDialog`.

However I am getting the following error message:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Application android.app.Activity.getApplication()' on a null object reference`

The error message is occurring here:

```
childExerciseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(ChildExerciseViewModel.class);
```

How can I avoid the error?

**AddExerciseDialog**

```
public class AddExerciseDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private EditText editTextExerciseName;
    private ChildExerciseViewModel childExerciseViewModel;
    String userEnteredExerciseName;
    int exerciseTypeID;
    Button cancelBtn;
    Button addBtn;
    Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        childExerciseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) context).get(ChildExerciseViewModel.class);
        //return view;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_add_exercise, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        editTextExerciseName = getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextExerciseName);
        addBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        cancelBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
                exerciseTypeID = mArgs.getInt("ExerciseTypeID");
                userEnteredExerciseName = editTextExerciseName.getText().toString();
                childExerciseViewModel.getAllChildExerciseNames().observe((FragmentActivity) context, this::checkIfChildExerciseNameAlreadyExists);
                // this checks if child exercise already exists, if so add error toast
            }

            private void checkIfChildExerciseNameAlreadyExists(List<String> childExercisesList) {
                for (int i = 0; i < childExercisesList.size(); i++) {

                    if (childExercisesList.contains(userEnteredExerciseName)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "An exercise with that name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        final ChildExercises childExercise = new ChildExercises(0, userEnteredExerciseName, null, exerciseTypeID);
                        childExerciseViewModel.insert(childExercise);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is AddExerciseDialog extending dialogfragment ?

Comment: yes `AddExerciseDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment`

Comment: then write the same code in oncreateview, their the view would always be available and will resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks for the response, `onCreateView` is not the same as `onCreateDialog` though. I would like to create a dialogBox popUp. Please could you clarify your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah onCreateView and onCreateDialog are not same, but it depends how you want to use your dialog, for your use case I'll suggest you to use it as a view as you need your viewmodel and viewmodel depends on view lifecycle that's why it will always be null in onCreateDialog. Moreover everything would almost be same if you move to onCreateView.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

use `this` intead of `getViewLifecycleOwner()`

Comment: This unfortunately does not work: cannot resolve method `getActivity()`

Comment: Required: Lifecycle Owner, Provided: onClickListener

Comment: use this like this@yourFragmentName. As my Fragment name is SelectDriverFragment. I'm using this@SelectDriverFragment instead of viewLifecycleOwner. and use @SuppressLint("FragmentLiveDataObserve") on top of my method. My problem is solved now.